# Windows 7 icons blank and don't function on Desktop, Taskbar and Start menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons

First I tried to download *Starcraft 2* on **Windows 7** and after *the installer* ran there was no way to launch it. I ran *the installer* again and then all my icons on the **computer**, on **desktop**, **taskbar** and **start menu** as well as in **windows explorer** turned into the *Blizzard* icon and opened the *Starcraft installer* when double clicked. Except for **MS Word** files, which open normally.

**AVG** scan found nothing, **windows** scan found and deleted some harmful stuff, I also deleted everything to do with the game. Now all the icons are blank (paper icon) and the open the "*choose the program you want to use to open this file*" page.

I can access **google chrome** by opening **help and support** from the **start menu** and finding a web link, and I can open **Windows explorer** by opening a file location from the task manager. Interestingly I managed to run a Microsoft game which now appears and runs normally in the start menu...

I am using an ASUS laptop with Windows 7 Pro, Intel Core 2Duo, 64 bit.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by tring a System Restore: [MS Feature Overview - System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore)

> System Restore returns your PC's system files and programs to a time when everything was working fine, potentially preventing hours of troubleshooting headaches. It won't affect your documents, pictures, or other data, and getting to it is simple: just type "system restore" in the Start menu search box.
>   In Windows 7, you can create more system restore points and see exactly what files will be removed or added when your PC is restored.

Comment: Thank you edusysadmin! System restore! Who would have known. 
I managed to run it, and everything is back to normal, albeit a little slow.